# How to include greater than or equal in numpy system of linear equations solver

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, linear-algebra

I'm trying to solve a system of linear equations (5 variables on 11 different equations/restrictions).

The problem I'm having is that the solution I'm looking for **can't be only equal** since I'm trying to optimize for a budget, it has to be **>= or <=** but I'm not sure how write that in numpy.

The equations are as follow (only a few to simplify):

- X/.07 >= 1728
- Y/.02 >= 4431
- Z/.05 >= 5409
- A/.005 >= 7138
- B/.01 >= 4897
- A + B + X + Y + Z >= 100781

Ideally I'd like to include others like:

- 9000 <= X <= 60000
- 9000 <= Y <= 60000
- 9000 <= Z <= 60000
- 9000 <= A <= 60000
- 9000 <= B <= 60000

But I'm not sure how to include them.

So far I Have

```
a = np.array([[1,0,0,0,0],
          [0,1,0,0,0],
          [0,0,1,0,0],
          [0,0,0,1,0],
          [0,0,0,0,1],
          [1,1,1,1,1]])

b = np.array([121204, 81069, 263260, 23541, 42964, 100781])

print(np.linalg.lstsq(a,b,rcond=None))
```

But clearly that's not what im looking for. (Notice b is simply the result of multiplying the right side by the denominator of the left hand)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As @bg2b mentioned, you can use `scipy.optimize.linprog`. A very similar answer was given here [Solve a system of linear equations and linear inequalities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48966934/solve-a-system-of-linear-equations-and-linear-inequalities)
, with a step-by-step walkthrough for the function.

Comment: That's great but I don't see how to work that with 5 variables, any idea?

Comment: Which variable are you optimizing for? I mean, you are looking for max or min? Is there any specific order (e.g. find the max for X, given that, the max for Y, etc..)?

Comment: this is for budget planning so ideally is maximizing all variables if possible, hence the 9000 <= # <= 60000

Comment: @Gorlomi I am sorry but this means nothing. Let's simplify the problem to see what I mean. Assume we have only 2 variables X and Y, with constraints 0.5 < X, Y < 1. And we also want X+Y < 1.2. What does it mean to maximize both X and Y? We can maximize their sum  and get X+Y = 1.2, but this is still a line, hence there is no unique point to achieve that. 
On the other hand, let's say we want to maximize for Y, then we would get Y=0.7 and X=0.5 (otherwise they would not satisfy  0.5 < X, Y < 1). I hope the point and the reason for the previous comment is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may want linear programming (optimize a linear function subject to linear equality and inequality constraints), not a least squares solver.

See scipy.optimize.linprog: 
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html

Comment: interesting! but how do I include 5 variables?

Comment: Well, where the documentation there refers to x, imagine "a vector of 5 values representing [A, B, X, Y, Z]", basically the same idea as when expressing a simple system of linear equations in matrix form.  As a simple example, the A_ub and b_ub mentioned there would be -a and -b from your little code snippet (negative because the optimizer constrains <= and you're wanting >=).  Then you have to pick something to minimize (because there are infinitely many solutions).  You might minimize A+B+X+Y+Z, in which case c=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]