# Solve linear Inequalities

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, inequalities

I want to solve a system of inequalities A x <= b, namely to visualize the set of solutions of this system. Are there any ways to do this in Python? The solutions I've found using the scipy library give only one vertex.

```
A = np.array([[-1, 1],
          [0, 1],
          [0.5, 1],
          [1.5, 1],
          [-1, 0],
          [0, -1]])
 b = np.array([1, 2, 3, 6, 0, 0])
```

Comment: I expanded quite a bit on my original answer... Check it out.

Comment: Related answer to aid in undestanding this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48966934/solve-a-system-of-linear-equations-and-linear-inequalities

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that [fillplots](https://fillplots.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#two-regions-two-py) is a superset of what you need. That should handle linear inequations very easily.

**Update**

I was thinking about this again, and I thought I would try to see what can be done without `fillplots`, just using standard libraries such as `scipy` and `numpy`.

In such a system of inequalities, each equation defines a half-space. The system is the intersection of all these half-spaces and is a convex set.

Finding the vertices of that set (for example, to plot them) is called the [Vertex enumeration problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_enumeration_problem). Fortunately, there are powerful algorithms to manipulate convex hulls, compute half-space intersections (and do many other wonderful things) in *n* dimensions. An example implementation is the [Qhull library](http://www.qhull.org/html/index.htm).

Even more fortunate for us, we can access aspects of that library directly via `scipy.spacial`, specifically: [`HalfspaceIntersection`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.HalfspaceIntersection.html) and [`ConvexHull`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html).

In the following:

1. We find a suitable feasible point, or `interior_point`, needed by `HalfspaceIntersection`.
2. In order to avoid warnings (and `Inf`, `nan` in the result) when the convex set is open, we augment the original system `Ax <= b` with constraints that define a bounding box (to be supplied by the caller, and also used as plotting boundaries).
3. We get the half-space intersections, and reorder them into a convex hull (a bit wasteful, but I didn't quite follow the order returned by `HalfspaceIntersection`, and in 2D the vertices of the hull are guaranteed to be in counterclockwise order).
4. We plot the convex hull (in red), and all the lines corresponding to the equations.

Here we go:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import HalfspaceIntersection, ConvexHull
from scipy.optimize import linprog

def feasible_point(A, b):
    # finds the center of the largest sphere fitting in the convex hull
    norm_vector = np.linalg.norm(A, axis=1)
    A_ = np.hstack((A, norm_vector[:, None]))
    b_ = b[:, None]
    c = np.zeros((A.shape[1] + 1,))
    c[-1] = -1
    res = linprog(c, A_ub=A_, b_ub=b[:, None], bounds=(None, None))
    return res.x[:-1]

def hs_intersection(A, b):
    interior_point = feasible_point(A, b)
    halfspaces = np.hstack((A, -b[:, None]))
    hs = HalfspaceIntersection(halfspaces, interior_point)
    return hs

def plt_halfspace(a, b, bbox, ax):
    if a[1] == 0:
        ax.axvline(b / a[0])
    else:
        x = np.linspace(bbox[0][0], bbox[0][1], 100)
        ax.plot(x, (b - a[0]*x) / a[1])

def add_bbox(A, b, xrange, yrange):
    A = np.vstack((A, [
        [-1,  0],
        [ 1,  0],
        [ 0, -1],
        [ 0,  1],
    ]))
    b = np.hstack((b, [-xrange[0], xrange[1], -yrange[0], yrange[1]]))
    return A, b

def solve_convex_set(A, b, bbox, ax=None):
    A_, b_ = add_bbox(A, b, *bbox)
    interior_point = feasible_point(A_, b_)
    hs = hs_intersection(A_, b_)
    points = hs.intersections
    hull = ConvexHull(points)
    return points[hull.vertices], interior_point, hs

def plot_convex_set(A, b, bbox, ax=None):
    # solve and plot just the convex set (no lines for the inequations)
    points, interior_point, hs = solve_convex_set(A, b, bbox, ax=ax)
    if ax is None:
        _, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.set_aspect('equal')
    ax.set_xlim(bbox[0])
    ax.set_ylim(bbox[1])
    ax.fill(points[:, 0], points[:, 1], 'r')
    return points, interior_point, hs

def plot_inequalities(A, b, bbox, ax=None):
    # solve and plot the convex set,
    # the inequation lines, and
    # the interior point that was used for the halfspace intersections
    points, interior_point, hs = plot_convex_set(A, b, bbox, ax=ax)
    ax.plot(*interior_point, 'o')
    for a_k, b_k in zip(A, b):
        plt_halfspace(a_k, b_k, bbox, ax)
    return points, interior_point, hs
```

**Tests**

(Your original system):

```
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (6, 3)

A = np.array([[-1, 1],
          [0, 1],
          [0.5, 1],
          [1.5, 1],
          [-1, 0],
          [0, -1]])
b = np.array([1, 2, 3, 6, 0, 0])

bbox = [(-1, 5), (-1, 4)]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
plot_convex_set(A, b, bbox, ax=ax[0])
plot_inequalities(A, b, bbox, ax=ax[1]);
```

[image]

A modified system that results in an open set:

```
A = np.array([
    [-1, 1],
    [0, 1],
    [-1, 0],
    [0, -1],
])
b = np.array([1, 2, 0, 0])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
plot_convex_set(A, b, bbox, ax=ax[0])
plot_inequalities(A, b, bbox, ax=ax[1]);
```

[image]

Comment: Hmmm... Not quite what I was looking for, as there are still lines to build on the set, but there's already progress!) Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean "lines to build on the set"?  You can just plot the convex hull and that is just the red polygon without the lines corresponding to the inequalities. In other words, you can remove the last two lines of `plot_inequalities` if you don't want to visualize the lines. I plotted them for demo purposes.

Comment: I'll try to figure it out. Your answer really helped me out, thank you!!!))

Comment: I modified the code: just use `plot_convex_set()` to get the left-side plot only (just the polygon of the convex set).

Comment: This answer is amazing. Exactly what I have been looking for - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent library pypoman which solves the vertex enumerate problem and can help with your problem, but unfortunately it only outputs the vertices of the set, not the visualization. The vertices may be disordered and without additional actions the visualization will not be correct. To overcome this problem, you can use the algorithms from this site https://habr.com/ru/post/144921/ (Graham scan or algo Jarvis).

Here is a sample code:

```
import pypoman
import cdd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def grahamscan(A):
    def rotate(A,B,C):
        return (B[0]-A[0])*(C[1]-B[1])-(B[1]-A[1])*(C[0]-B[0])

    n = len(A) 
    if len(A) == 0:
        return A

    P = np.arange(n)
    for i in range(1,n):
        if A[P[i]][0]<A[P[0]][0]: 
            P[i], P[0] = P[0], P[i] 
    for i in range(2,n): 
        j = i
        while j>1 and (rotate(A[P[0]],A[P[j-1]],A[P[j]])<0):
            P[j], P[j-1] = P[j-1], P[j]
            j -= 1
    S = [P[0],P[1]] 
    for i in range(2,n):
        while rotate(A[S[-2]],A[S[-1]],A[P[i]])<0:
            del S[-1] 
        S.append(P[i])
    return S

def compute_poly_vertices(A, b):
    b = b.reshape((b.shape[0], 1))
    mat = cdd.Matrix(np.hstack([b, -A]), number_type='float')
    mat.rep_type = cdd.RepType.INEQUALITY
    P = cdd.Polyhedron(mat)
    g = P.get_generators()
    V = np.array(g)
    vertices = []
    for i in range(V.shape[0]):
        if V[i, 0] != 1: continue
        if i not in g.lin_set:
            vertices.append(V[i, 1:])
    return vertices


A = np.array([[-1, 1],
              [0, 1],
              [0.5, 1],
              [1.5, 1],
              [-1, 0],
              [0, -1]])
b = np.array([1, 2, 3, 6, 0, 0])

vertices = np.array(compute_poly_vertices(A, b))
print(vertices)
vertices = np.array(vertices[grahamscan(vertices)])

x, y = vertices[:, 0], vertices[:, 1]

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, title="Solution")

ax.fill(x, y, linestyle = '-', linewidth = 1, color='gray', alpha=0.5)
ax.scatter(x, y, s=10, color='black', alpha=1)
```

I am also writing an intvalpy library for my master's thesis (no documentation yet, only examples on githab). The function lineqs can also help you. It solves the system A x >= b and outputs ordered vertices and visualizes the set.

For your problem, the code looks like this:

```
from intvalpy import lineqs
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[-1, 1],
              [0, 1],
              [0.5, 1],
              [1.5, 1],
              [-1, 0],
              [0, -1]])
b = np.array([1, 2, 3, 6, 0, 0])

lineqs(-A, -b)
```

Comment: Your answer also fits, and also shows the vertices. Only where did you use the pypoman library itself?
Your function lineqs(-A, -b) also gave the correct result  Conveniently so short, but the documentation is still extremely important.

Comment: I took the compute_poly_vertices function from the library itself and modified it a bit. You can look it up on GitHub, it's easy to find there. I hope your problem is solved =)

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import cdd as pcdd
from fractions import Fraction
A = np.array(
    [[-1, 1],
     [0, 1],
     [Fraction(1,2), 1],
     [Fraction(3,2), 1],
     [-1, 0],
     [0, -1]]
    )
b = np.array([[1], [2], [3], [6], [0], [0]])
M = np.hstack( (b, -A) )

mat = pcdd.Matrix(M, linear=False, number_type="fraction") 
mat.rep_type = pcdd.RepType.INEQUALITY

poly = pcdd.Polyhedron(mat)
ext = poly.get_generators()
print(ext)
```

Comment: Please explain your solution rather than just pasting code